# AudioKit - Temporary file size is too big

Tags: swift, audiokit

I am using AudioKit's AKNodeRecorder for recording audio.

While recording audio it generates CAF file in a temp directory. if we save it with exportAsynchronously it creates a new file with m4a extension in document directory.

The CAF file generates in temp directory is too big in size.
1 sec of audio takes
1 sec = 360000 bytes = 0.36 MB
Disk space

while after exporting m4a file takes
1 sec = 32000 bytes = 0.032 MB
Disk space

The m4a space is good for recording an audio. but the CAF file size is too big for long time recording.

I have to record 2.5 hrs of audio at one time, which will generate 3.6 GB of CAF file

Can we use less disk space while recording?