# Audiokit merging two converted files gives com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-50

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit

I have two wav files that I recorded using Audiokit in caf and then converted to wav like this:

Converter options:

```
func getAKConverterOptions()-> AKConverter.Options{
        var options = AKConverter.Options()
        // any options left nil will assume the value of the input file
        options.format = "wav"
        options.sampleRate = 8000
        options.bitRate = 16
        options.channels = 1
        options.bitDepth = 16
        options.eraseFile = true
        options.isInterleaved = true
        return options
    }
```

Conversion:

```
let converter = AKConverter(inputURL: self.getFilePath(name: self.primaryRecording, extension: "caf"), outputURL: self.getFilePath(name: self.primaryRecording, extension: "wav"), options: self.getAKConverterOptions())
converter.start { (error) in
}
```

The files are converted successfully.

Then I read both files in `AKAudioFile` like:

```
let file = try AKAudioFile(forReading: self.getFilePath(name: self.primaryRecording, extension: "wav"))

let basefile = try AKAudioFile(forReading: self.getFilePath(name: self.baseRecording, extension: "wav"))
```

Then I append the files like:

```
basefile.appendAsynchronously(file: file, baseDir: .documents, name: self.baseRecording.replacingOccurrences(of: ".wav", with: "")) { (file, error) in

}
```

This always returns an error:

> AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioFile.mm:472:-[AVAudioFile
>   writeFromBuffer:error:]: (ExtAudioFileWrite(_imp->_extAudioFile,
>   buffer.frameLength, buffer.audioBufferList)): error -50
>   AKAudioFile+Processing.swift:appendedBy(file:baseDir:name:):155:ERROR
>   AKAudioFile: cannot writeFromBuffer Error: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-50 "(null)" UserInfo={failed
>   call=ExtAudioFileWrite(_imp->_extAudioFile, buffer.frameLength,
>   buffer.audioBufferList)}
>
> AKAudioFile+ProcessingAsynchronously.swift:queueAppendAsyncProcess(sourceFile:appendedFile:baseDir:name:completionHandler:):565:Failed
>   Appending file "BaseRecording.wav" -> Error: "Error
>   Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-50 "(null)" UserInfo={failed
>   call=ExtAudioFileWrite(_imp->_extAudioFile, buffer.frameLength,
>   buffer.audioBufferList)}" (process #0)

What am I doing wrong? My AKAudio Setup is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772495/audiokit-recording-file-size-too-big). I had to convert the files to reduce their size but after reducing the size, now the audio merging process is throwing error.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @CarlesEstevadeordal Sadly I didn't. I ended up using FFMPEG to merge the files which did it without any issues.